# Android resources by gender

Tags: android, android-resources

Can someone recommend me a good way to manage application resources, mostly strings per gender (like multi language application).
I mean to languages that has different grammar for male and female (like Russian).
Lets assume that I know the user gender.
Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to support multiple languages in your application I highly recommend watching [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54BSTOzbc_o). It's from this years Google IO conference and gives you a quick overview of the Android tools for multi language support. I really enjoyed this talk as I didn't know the platform had so many built in features for internationalization.

Comment: I mean single language like Russian where if I wont to ask user the same question it written different for male and female. So for the same TextView (for example) I need 2 different texts by user gender.

Comment: Yes I'd still recommend watching this talk. It will show you how to use the tools required to accomplish what you're looking for. At the very least it will give you a great starting point.

Comment: The link written in this answer is no longer valid. I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54BSTOzbc_o) is the talk on YouTube

Answer (score 1):

whats stopping you from asking for gender at the setup stage, then saving that to settings.

then when you get to a gender text, it references the settings

Comment: I know the gender, I just have about 20 screens and each contains a few TextViews and Buttons which has text by geneder, and I don't won't to use if-else on each view.

Comment: you can make a table of evry single russian word which has bith male and female annotations, then create a function. the function will take two parameters, one is the location to the settings file where it tells the user's sex. the second is the word to annotate. But i think thats overly complecated. I'm sure if you call them ALL 'HE' no one will mind

Comment: Alternitatively, but similarly, write the script twice, onc for man, once for woman. UPut it in a array, Question[0][0]: How are you(male)? Question[0][1] How are You(fem)? Question[1][0] :where do you eat(male)? Question[1][1]: Where do you eat (female)?   Question[2][0]  ...etc

Answer (score -1):

For handling gender, I have been using formatting string resources: [Formatting and Styling string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Here is an example of a string resource

```
<string name="title">%1$s is amazing!</string>
```

In code do this:

```
textView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.title), "She"));
```